# Optimizing replace function in a binary tree to be tail recursive

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm trying to optimize this function to be tail recursive in Scala.

```
  /**
   * Replaces all instances of the original tree with the replacement tree
   * @param originalTree - the tree that needs to be replaced
   * @param replacementTree - the tree that is being put into the original tree
   * @param parentTree - the tree that is being searched for instances to replace
   * @tparam T
   * @return
   */
  def replace[T](originalTree : BinaryTree[T], replacementTree : BinaryTree[T])(implicit parentTree : BinaryTree[T] = this) : BinaryTree[T] = {
    //TODO: Optimize this into a tail recursive function
    parentTree match {
      case Empty => if (originalTree == Empty) replacementTree else Empty
      case l : Leaf[T] => if (l == originalTree) replacementTree else l
      case n : Node[T] => if (n == originalTree) replacementTree else
        Node(n.v,
          replace(originalTree,replacementTree)(n.l),
          replace(originalTree,replacementTree)(n.r))
    }
  }
```

As the Scaladoc says, it replaces all instances of `originalTree` in the `parentTree` with `replacementTree`.

This is a really straightforward recursive function, however optimizing it to a tail recursive function is tripping me up.

I've started building a helper function inside of `replace` with the following structure

```
@tailrec
def loop(tree : BinaryTree[T], accum : List[Node[T]]) : BinaryTree[T] = tree match {
  case Empty => if (originalTree == Empty) replacementTree else Empty
  case Leaf(x) => if (Leaf(x) == tree) replacementTree else Leaf(x)
  case Node(v,l,r) => ???

}
```

Here are the definitions of [`BinaryTree`](https://github.com/Christewart/scalacoin/blob/script/src/main/scala/org/scalacoin/util/BinaryTree.scala#L8) and [`Node`](https://github.com/Christewart/scalacoin/blob/script/src/main/scala/org/scalacoin/util/BinaryTree.scala#L159)